# How to make MapboxGL marker popup auto pan so it's fully visible on the map?

Tags: mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I have a marker and a popup that I use that opens when the marker is clicked. The original Mapbox API had `autoPan` setting, but MapboxGL does not. How would I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

To enable auto-pan for popups all you have to do is **not specify a popup anchor**.

From docs:

> anchor

> A string indicating the part of the popup that should be positioned
> closest to the coordinate, set via Popup#setLngLat . Options are
> 'center' , 'top' , 'bottom' , 'left' , 'right' , 'top-left' ,
> 'top-right' , 'bottom-left' , and 'bottom-right' . **If unset**, the
> anchor will be dynamically set to ensure the popup falls within the
> map container with a preference for 'bottom' .

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#popup

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, `autoPan` will make sure the popup is in the map view when it is opened. To accomplish this, you could use `map.flyTo()` or `map.jumpTo()` to jump to the popup location.

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Ltypbkdc/

Comment: You're right about `autoPan` making sure the popup is visible. The problem I'm talking about is if the marker is at the very top right corner of the map, and the user opens the popup, I need to calculate exactly to what coordinates to move the map to (up and to the right), so the popup becomes visible. Not only that but there's gotta be some sort of pixels-to-coordinates conversion if the popup's size is dynamic.